# How to change the size of the Drawable in TextView in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable, spannablestring

I want to know how to update a Drawable in a TextView, so I write the following code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView mText;
    private ColorDrawable mColorDrawable;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);
        mColorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.RED);
        mColorDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 100);
        SpannableString string = new SpannableString("This is a color box: /box, right?");
        string.setSpan(new ImageSpan(mColorDrawable), 21, 25, Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        mText.setText(string);

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mColorDrawable.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
                mColorDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, 200, 200);
                mText.invalidate();
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

The expected result is that the `/box` is replaced with a red square. After 1 second, it becomes bigger and its color turns into yellow.

And here are the screenshots before and after the color of the box changes.

[image: Before]

[image: After]

As you can see, the color is changed but the size is not changed properly. Also, the text after the box isn't moved rightwards but is covered by the box.

So my question is, how to make the TextView re-layout the Drawables and text, if not using `setText()` once more time?

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass "int size" inside run() and then add setTextSize(size) and setBounds:

```
  int size= 20; //you can change that later
  Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
             public void run() {
            mColorDrawable.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            mColorDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, 200, 200);
            mText.invalidate();

            size= size+ 20;
            mText.setTextSize(size); 
            mColorDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, size, size);

        }
    }, 1000);
}
```